# KAFKA Producer API Vs JMS Producer API

Tags: apache-kafka, jms

High level Design of application :

Upstream system sends stream of data, data is received by Java Application. Using KAFKA as data store, logstash will publish stored data in Elastic index, and all the application will use elastic search query to get the data.

Problem : To publish data from Java application to KAFKA, which API Kafka JMS client or Java Kafka Producer/Consumer API should be used?

As per kafka documentation, If you are interested in writing new Java applications then you are encouraged to use the Java Kafka Producer/Consumer APIs as they provide advanced features not available when using the kafka-jms-client https://docs.confluent.io/current/clients/kafka-jms-client/docs/index.html .

Also as per KAFKA documentation it is not typical Messgaing broker and not all JMS concepts map 1:1 kafka.

Is there any benefit of using JMS API for KAFKA since KAFKA is not typical Messaging broker [and application will be still tightly couple to KAFKA] and not all JMS concepts can be mapped to kafka?

Comment: "Kafka Producer/Consumer should be used?" YES

Comment: used kafka producer API since Kafka does not support lot of functionality of the JMS API. So even if KAFKA JMS client API is used, implementation will be tightly coupled with kafka.